# EF Core fetching the whole object for a null check

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

I have `Book` and `Author` domain classes, and `BookDto` and `AuthorDto` classes which are a subselection of their respective domain classes.

Somewhere in the app, I have to expose an `IQueryable<BookDto>` rather than an `IQueryable<Book>`, So, I've written the following code to do the conversion, nothing complicated:

```
var queryableDto = dbContext.Books.Select(book => new BookDto
{
    Name = book.Name,
    ...
    Author = book.Author == null ? null : new AuthorDto
    {
        Id = book.Author.Id,
        Name = book.Author.Name,
        ...
    }
});
```

And then I've done this:

```
var dtos = queryableDto.Select(bDto => new BookDto
{
    Name = bDto.Name,
    Author = bDto.Author == null ? null : new AuthorDto() { Name = bDto.Author.Name }
}).ToList();
```

But there is a big problem with the null-check in my second query (where it says `Author = bDto.Author == null ? null : new...`). Because when I say: `bDto.Author == null` what happens is that Entity Framework retrieves the whole Author object with all of its columns from the database, but that obviously shouldn't be the case and it wasn't what I intended to do. These null-checks get translated to SQL when you're working with an `IQueryable` of domain classes (like in the first code block), but not when you're doing something like this.

I also can't get rid of the null-check since I have to find out whether the book has an author or not. (I know that in real life there can't be a book without an author but this is just an example)

So, is there a way out of this really? How can I tell Entity Framework that when I say `bDto.Author == null` retrieving the whole thing is not really what I'm intending to do?

Comment: It is a EF Core limitation. Wait for fix, you can not do anything. I think there are already a lot of github issues for such case.

Comment: Are you using EFC 2.x? If yes, you are kind of lucky because in EFC3.x the same throws exception - looks like one can't do *any* condition on optionally projected member. Haven't checked EFC5.0 (preview) if it's better in that regard.

Comment: @IvanStoev Well, I haven't tried it with 2.x, but I have tried it with both 3.x and 5.0.0 RC and neither actually threw an exception, but they both have the problem I explained.

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi Actually I've tried `queryableDto.Where(dto => dto.Author != null)` and similar which throws. Projection could have different behavior (the one you explained, I trust you). My point was that there is definitely a EF Core issues/bugs/defects/limitations with post operators on such projection, and as such it is probably impossible to fight with.

Comment: Guys, EF Core should track null check projections. It is not so hard and I've done the same task in our LINQ provider - doeable without harming animals.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh, okay. I hadn't tried `.Where(dto => dto.Author != null)` so I didn't know that it would throw an exception. And yes you're right, EF Core doesn't do a good job about this. I've become hopeless at this point as I haven't found any solution to this problem :( So, I guess it is probably "impossible to fight with" as you said. Although, I would welcome any suggestions as to what other strategies I could implement to achieve something similar.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv Well, it doesn't, in this case, unfortunately.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv But you also said it's not possible and we can't do anything about it your first comment :) Can we do something about it? Or we can't?

Comment: @AmirHosseinAhmadi, if EF Core can not track projection transformation in such case, you can not do anything. They need information about fields, from which source the came. it's like playing music in reverse order: DTO property -> null check expression which complicates identifying for which find it is related . Also there is not trivial navigation property handling.

Comment: I saw you filled [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/22792) in EF Core tracker. Looks like 5.0 RC2 would fix it :)

Comment: @IvanStoev Well, it's actually not fixed unfortunately cuz I noticed that guy made a mistake in his repro. I responded to him there. I was ecstatic for a couple of seconds until I realized what was missing in his repro! :)

Comment: i think your understanding is off... to do a select first implies its going to do the first projection as a ToList.... which will fetch everything... , rather end with the select from the able on the iqueryable. queryableDto <= where stuff then select stuff.., futher urs is made more complex as you are doing nesting navigation properties... just use `include`.... dbContext.Books.Inlcude(x=>Author).... do your where and select...

Comment: further im pretty sure that `I have to expose an IQueryable<BookDto>` breaks some coding design principle. aka you should not expose somethinge which isn't really IQueryable as that point as its already be "bound". instead well you would need to expressions to end with the select of BookDto, which means you would have to build up quite the expression tree to handle all that, basically u would be writing framework.. code. which would have to handle all the routes. this is quite complex. anyway that is my understanding.

Comment: it would be better to use `Includes` have u looked into that... and return a IQueryable<Book> with the includes preform the where and finally the select returning List<BookDto> once it leaves the repo.

Comment: @Seabizkit No, I know what I'm doing and I'm not breaking any programming principles. I know all about `Include` and `ToList`, etc. they are not useful and relevant to the problem I'm trying to solve in this case. I eventually resolved the problem by using `bDto.Author.Id == null` instead of `bDto.Author == null`.

Comment: @Seabizkit I didn't explain the whole situation so the question might sound weird to some, but it in fact isn't. I'm just trying to expose an `IQueryable` to a GraphQL server framework, and that shouldn't be an `IQueryable` of my domain classes since I want to abstract away certain complexities of my domain classes/database table structure that are irrelevant to my GraphQL API clients. Nonetheless, thank you for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

So you  have a one-to-many relation between Authors and Books: every Author wrote zero or more Books, every Book has been written by exactly one Author, namely the Author that the foreign key AuthorId refers to.

I use full entity framework. For your problem I would use the virtual properties of the Book. Entity framework knows the relation between Authors and Books and will create the correct (Group-)join for you.

I've heard rumours that the core version of entity framework has some limitations in using the virtual properties, although I have never examined them. Therefore I'll give you the solution using the virtual properties, and one where you do the join yourself.

### Use virtual properties.

If you've followed the [entity framework conventions](https://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/code-first-conventions.aspx), your classes will similar to the following:

```
class Author
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Author wrote zero or more Books (one-to-many)
    public virtual ICollection<Book> Books {get; set;}
}

class Book
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Name {get; set;}
    ...

    // Every Book has been written by exactly one Author, using foreign key
    public int AuthorId {get; set;}
    public virtual Author Author {get; set; }
}
```

The solution can be like the following:

```
public MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Author> Authors {get; set;}
    public DbSet<Book> Books {get; set;}

    public IQueryable<BookDto> BookDtos => this.Books.Select(book => new BookDto
    {
        Id = book.Id,
        Name = book.Name,
        ...

        // A BookDto has exactly one Author
        Author = new AuthorDto
        {
            Id = book.Author.Id,
            Name = book.Author.Name,
            ...
        },
    });
}
```

If you want to force the use of BookDtos instead of Books, you can wrap the query in an interface, and provide the interface instead of the full MyDbContext.

### Do the join yourself

```
IQueryable<BookDto> BookDtos => this.Books.Join(
    this.Authors,

    book => book.AuthorId,       // from every book take the foreign key to Author
    author => author.BookId,     // from every Author take the primary key

    // parameter resultSelector: for every Book with its one-and-only Author,
    // make one new BookDto:
    (book, author) => new BookDto
    {
        Id = book.Id,
        Name = book.Name,
        ...

        Author = new AuthorDto
        {
            Id = book.Author.Id,
            Name = book.Author.Name,
            ...
        },
    });
```

And if you want to get the Authors with their Books:

```
IQueryable<AuthorDto> AuthorDtos => this.Authors.GroupJoin(
    this.Books,

    author = author.Id,      // from every Author take the primary key
    book = book.AuthorId,    // from every Book take the foreign key to Author

    // parameter resulSelector: take every author with his zero or more Books
    // to create one new AuthorDto:
    (author, booksOfThisAuthor) => new AuthorDto
    {
        Id = author.Id,
        Name = author.Name,
        ...

        Books = booksOfThisAuthor.Select(book => new BookDto
        {
            Id = book.Author.Id,
            Name = book.Author.Name,
            ...
        }),
    });
```

> If, in a one-to-many relation, you want "items with their zero or more sub-items" use GroupJoin and start on the one-side. If you want "items with the one-and-only item that the foreign key refers to", use Join and start on the many side.

If you examine the [overload of Queryable.GroupJoin with parameter resultSelector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.queryable.groupjoin?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Queryable_GroupJoin__4_System_Linq_IQueryable___0__System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1__System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___1___2___System_Linq_Expressions_Expression_System_Func___0_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___1____3___), you'll see that `booksOfThisAuthor` is of type `System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TInner>,TResult>>`. So it is not `IQueryable<...>`. So if you expect that users don't want all Books, or not the complete BookDto, I'm not sure if this method is efficient.

Comment: Not sure that this is the answer for the original question. But a little comment of proposed realization. Better to create extension methods `IQueryable<BookDto> ToDto(this IQueryable<Boo> query)` it will improve usage and can be applied to prepared IQueryable.

Comment: I agree, the extension method is better. I didn't mention it, because I didn't want to overflow the questioner with information. The kind of question gave me the impresdion that LINQ is a fairly new technology for him